# What good reason to hang long cable carrying electric current high above the ground?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electrical-resistance, insulators

Assume no flooding or other natural disasters to damage the cable if it is laid beneath the ground, then what good reason for them to be suspended high above the ground? The cables are insulated and only carry electrical current so if money is no problem then is there any good reason to keep them off the ground? I think the reason for the suspension is due to the fact that exposed cable can shock gravesrobbers accidentally since they didn't have more concrete back then but I suspect there is a sound scientific reason too, right?

Comment: Tradeoffs in cost, schedule, and performance - classic engineering issues.

Comment: Related: A recent [Veritasium video](https://youtu.be/bHIhgxav9LY?t=680)

Answer (score 6):

Going underground is more expensive then suspending in air in at least two ways.

Initially having to dig a trench or use a "mole" (which is less disruptive) and then when there is a need for a repair (identifying the fault and then access to it).

There is also the problem of dissipating the heat generated when the cables are carrying electrical power because cables have resistance.  In the air this is relatively simple because the cables do not have to have to be wrapped in an insulator and then surrounded by a conduit containing oil to prevent overheating.

Comment: I want to point out that in Greece about half the  wild fires come from the areal wires, it used to be even from large birds shorting them and falling on the ground, and the areal  uninsulated are slowly replaced by braided insulated wires . In very forested regions there is a long range plan to go underground.

Comment: *In very forested regions there is a long range plan to go underground.* which undoubtedly is initially going to be very costly and so can only be done in (small) steps?

Comment: Right, costly and hard to do as there are  rocks etc underground in those regions

Comment: @Farcher yes but OP dismissed costs:  "So if money is no problem then is there any good reason to keep them off the ground?". This answer just ignores that.

Comment: @annav, When have you seen birds go anywhere near high-voltage transmission lines? Stand underneath one, and the hum and crackle in the air ought to give you a good idea of why birds keep away. I don't know anything about Greece, but here in the U.S.A., Power lines start fires because the owners don't cut the brush growing beneath them as often as they should do. In hot weather, the lines droop. When everybody turns on their air conditioners (because of the hot weather) the lines droop even more. And hot weather, when the power lines hang at their lowest, also is when fire danger is greatest.

Comment: @SolomonSlow  sure that is the main reason,  (though most forested regions belong to government and in a mountainous country lines have to go through them )  but my son was a witness to the start of  a fire by a large bird when he was doing his army duty in a forested area. It landed on the  column supporting the lines , shorted and fell on the brush beneath. Fortunately there was a number of soldiers that saw it, and they rushed and put the fire off. Also see this photo, what hum and crackle? https://energized.edison.com/stories/why-can-birds-sit-safely-on-power-lines

Comment: @annav, Re, "see this photo," That's not what i had in mind when I said, "high voltage." I was thinking, [more like this](https://img.tdworld.com/files/base/ebm/tdworld/image/2019/04/tdworld_17064_bloomberg_china_uhv.png). Stand underneath something like that, and you'll hear it. The main lines that supply my neighborhood are (I think) 24kV. Birds will roost on those. They don't make any hum or crackle.

Answer (score 2):

As the OP points out, the damage from flooding and other natural disasters, as well as the costs are the reasons for placing the cables above the ground. If these didn't matter, placing them underground would be better than keeping them in the open air. Note that costs involve not only actually placing the cable udnerground, but also planning a route for it (which can be complicated in urban areas), as well as identifying the breakage points, performing repair and simply replacing old cables.

Comment: Well, megavolt DC transmission lines are pretty hard to bury underground since the insulation is pretty tough to do.

Answer (score 2):

Several reasons, some of them more apparent than others

As you already pointed out: **Damage from environmental conditions**. Earthquakes and flooding are problems in many places around the world, and underground lines are exceedingly expensive to repair. The whole process of locating faults underground is time consuming, and they are not exactly just copper lines down there, but have complicated insulation requirements for field propagation reasons*.

**Cost of initial construction** Obviously, above ground high voltage lines are cheaper to construct, and much cheaper to upgrade.

**Near field energy propagation** As alluded to in the first point, electrical conductors do not exactly transmit power in the metal itself. Rather electrical power is transmitted through electromagnetic fields, and the conductor merely provides you a way of constraining the electric field into a neat tubes. All conducting materials near the wire also interfere with the electromagnetic field created, and constrain them. This robs you some of the power transmitted, at least in AC lines. You can think of this in terms of magnetic field saturation, or in terms of parasitic capacitance. Earth conducts electricity, especially when wet, and wires suspended above ground have better efficiency

Answer (score 1):

The very long power cables are run at very high voltages to minimize resistive losses. They also radiate. Both are reasons for putting them up high.

Comment: They _radiate_ what? Radiation? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Aganju - an ac transmission line is a nice long antenna.

Comment: @JonCuster : _I_ know that, but not everyone. But the answer is just very thin, it repeats generic information without really answering the question: _why_ exactly can’t / wouldn’t you put ‘very high voltages’ and ‘radiating’ under the earth??